# Arduino language

Tags: programming, arduino-builder

I'm learning with my school Arduino and how to use it etc.

I know Swift and a little bit of HTML and I would like to learn Arduino language, because I think it's easy!

What are the best resources for learning Arduino?
What are the best programs to write Arduino?
Thanks!

Comment: As FYI, there is a free/commercial [Swift for Arduino](https://www.swiftforarduino.com/) available. I've not tried it ... yet. Just noting the option.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to learn Arduino language, because I think it's easy!

it is C/C++.

Comment: Ok....  I dont know why, but when im writing Arduino, its not that hard like c/c++ .   Thanks

Comment: Maybe you find it easy because you have never written anything complex in it. And as arduino atmel chips are limited in memory, you wont write there complex applications...

Comment: @Divisadero οκ. I understand this. I have wrote complex code..   I have connected to an Arduino UNO an thermal censor, a temperature-humidity censor and a 16pin LCD 11x8 (I think, or 11x6 :)) ).   This code was my most complex. (I am learning Arduino with my school for almost a year.)

Comment: @AlexKordatzakis Do not take it personally, but what you have mentioned are not complex projects at all. I guess you have used the libraries for these projects. I suggest you look into the libraries and try to understand them.

Comment: @Divisadero 1st. I'm not taking it personally. :))   2) I didn't said that I have wrote the most complex code in Arduino..   3) For the libraries, should I download the arduino program, or just browse them?

Comment: 'Arduino program' is Arduino IDE [integrated development environment]. Here is some documentation for libraries: https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/libraries and here is some source code https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/libraries You can find more directly in Arduino IDE folders.

Answer (score 1):

To begin as a newbie get started with the inbuilt examples that are already given.You will learn one by one and its easy to understand anyways.Try few simple codes like LED BLINK,LED WITH SWITCH, SENSOR INPUT AND OUTPUT USING SERIAL MONITOR and you will get used to with the ARDUINO IDE.

Ofcourse the best site is www.arduino.cc but try few pdfs for Arduino beginners which are available on the internet.Try youtube if you are having any trouble working out with just text information.

Go through the book "ARDUINO PROJECTS FOR DUMMIES"
LINK: http://www.dummies.com/store/product/Arduino-Projects-For-Dummies.productCd-1118551478.html

check out this link:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/getting-started-with-arduino-a-beginners-guide/

Answer (score 1):

I guess Arduino is not the best language to learn as a beginner if you are interested in programming. Try Python, C#, JavaScript. Or directly C++ (which Arduino is actually).

Arduino has too specific usage and is limited. You wont use OOP here very often and will miss a lot of programming principles and practices.

Comment: Ok. But I'm already learning. 2 Languages. I started with Swift and now I'm in HTML.  I will stop here, and when I learn very smoothly to use these two languages I will move to C++. What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I havent't noticed Swift. My bad.

Comment: Is it good you mean?

Comment: It is not about being good or bad language. Who am I to say if one programming language is better or worse. But one can say if language is suitable for getting into programming for beginners. For me, personally, C# seems to be best for beginners. It is powerfull enough to learn you OOP, you can try design patterns and .NET contains enough frameworks to try client applications, web and SOA programming. Compared to C++ it abstract more difficult concepts you can grasp later. On the other hand, python seems to be to be too flexible for beginner.

Comment: I appreciate for giving me these advices!  But now I have to learn two languages and I like these languages.. thank you for the help anyway!!

Comment: Sure, I was talking in general. Acutally I have only basic knowledge about swift (as it targets apple), but I guess it is suitable as well. Good luck on your path.

Answer (score 0):

Best resources:

- Official website: [www.arduino.cc](https://www.arduino.cc/)
- This site (duh)

I don't know what you mean with 'best programs' ... that depends on what you want. My 'best program' is probably not your 'best program'